# Bad Request, Invalid Json error play2 on Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play 2.1.3 and I have a very simple app as below:

package controllers

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
object App extends Controller {
  def sectors = Action(parse.tolerantJson) { request=>
    Ok(Json.obj("Name"->"Scala"))
  }  
}
```

And my route is defined as below:

```
GET     /sectors                    controllers.App.sectors
```

Of course when I remove parse.tolerantJson the application works, In my application I need to use parse.tolerantJson method.

I receive the following error in the browser:

```
Bad request
For request 'GET /sectors' [Invalid Json]
```

Comment: What is the JSON content that you send when you get the "Bad request" response ?

Comment: I am just opening the page in a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tolerantJson` is the parser used to **parse** the **Request**.

When you define your action with `parse.json` or `parse.tolerantJson`, you say that the Request received must contain a json body, and must be sent with a JSON content/type.

In your case, you're just **sending** Json in the **Response** (not receiving Json in the request). And play tries to parse a null body as Json, so you've that error.

The Json content-type will be automatically added to your response (bacause Play knows how to render a Json, with `Writable[JsValue]`), so you've nothing to do.